# C data segment identification

Tags: c, static, data-segment

If I declare

```
  static int a ;// globally and 
  static int a ; // locally in one function
```

So now there are two instances of a ..

I know all static variables goes into data segment but how they are differentiated in data segment which one is local and which one is global ??

Comment: Just look in the map file and tell us..

Comment: i don't know exactly what you mean, but "a" is just a name you give to a variable, the compiler only knows its address. When you reference the `global a` it has its address and `local a` has its own as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can in fact go further: you can declare

```
static int a;
```

at file scope in two or more separate files contributing to your program.  Each such declaration in a different scope declares a separate variable.  Thus, given

**f.c:**

```
static int a;

int f() {
    static int a;
    return 0;
}
```

---

**main.c**

```
static int a;

int f(void);

int main() {
    return f();
}
```

---

There are three separate static variables associated with the name `a` in different places.  It is the compiler and linker's job to arrange for the correct storage to be associated with each variable reference.